# Connect Content Manager Server with two translation systems in SDL Web8

Tags: web8, translation-manager, worldserver, language-cloud

As I know, there are three translation systems of SDL - Translation Manager System, SDL Language Cloud and Worldserver.
Now, I'd like to connect Content Manager Server with translation system. Can we connect with both SDL Language and Worldserver. Taking cost into account, some contents can be translated by Machine Translation so it's no need to send them to Worldserver.
However, when I installed Translation Manager in Content Manager Server, I could only select one translation system type from list(Please refer to the image below). Dose this mean one Content Manager System only can connect to one translation system?
[image]
Any information would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OOTB, it's only one translation system per CMS. There might be a way to hack it though...

Comment: You can use different translation systems in the same CM, but not in the same publication. The question sounds like you would want to choose the engine _per job_ and that is currently not possible.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the translation system you select in the installer, you can still configure different translation systems in a single Tridion CM, but it will be a single translation system per Blueprint hierarchy.

For instance in the picture below, 200 Content EN is an English source publication configured to use Language Cloud for any of its child publications setup as translation target.

200 Example Content EN is an English source publication configured to use World Server for any of its child publications setup as translation target.

[image: multi translation blueprint]

You configure the translation system from the translatrion source publication properties, in the translation tab:

[image: translation options]

Answer (score 3):

SDL Language Cloud is enabled by default. So in installer you can just select World Server and you will get both.

If you already installed and want to add World Server to TM - see [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-C493D2B7-7B4F-484F-A536-8CD78C6041BE&addHistory=true&query=%253CWorldServer&scope=&tid=0c607282-04fb-4a90-8676-d3a2dee8f7fa&filename=GUID-C493D2B7-7B4F-484F-A536-8CD78C6041BE.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-C493D2B7-7B4F-484F-A536-8CD78C6041BE&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3D%253CWorldServer&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1478000301394&currentQuery=%253CWorldServer&currentScope=)

It is indeed beter to separate different translation systems in different publications. See previous answer.